# storyboard segue from a tablecell an its Detail Disclosure Button

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, segue

I want to segue from a tablecell to two different viewcontrollers
if clicked in the cell or clicked on the cells Detail Disclosure Button.

If I ctrl-drag the second segue, the first is deleted.
What am I doing wrong?

Tnx
Mica

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you can link a specific detail disclosure button w/ a segue.  My storyboards are extremely programatic b/c I use alot of custom CGRect etc..

so I tend to use something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerIdentifer" sender:self];
}
```

for reference this is an extremely good example project on storyboards and tableviews.  there's a link to the project at the bottom also.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Comment: Tnx, I hope I read the article correctly, but what´s not clear to me is, how an when the segue with the id: @"ViewControllerIdentifer" is created.

Comment: if you go into the Interface builder and look at the view controller, there is an area to type in the "identifier" under "title" (4 tab is Xcode 4).  just type in it there.  The more complicated your coding is the more you'll be calling using identifier vs. a linking segue in the IB.

Comment: @mica I think the correct answer is that you ctrl-drag a segue from the table view to the next controller, instead of from the table cell - you do this by selecting the table view controller in the navigator left of the storyboard. This gives you a segue which you can trigger programmatically as above, but which won't be triggered by simply touching the cell.

Comment: I control drag from a detail disclosure indicator to the view controller in the storyboard and the segue is automatically triggered (i.e., no need to invoke `performSegueWithIdentifier:`).