# Distinguishing taps on UITableViewCell in general from taps on its accessory button in particular

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiaccessoryview

I would like to implement a `UITableViewController` that works in a similar fashion to the *Episodes* (under the *My Podcasts*) view in the iOS 7 *Podcasts* app in that its cells should perform one segue if I tap on the (left part of the) cell and perform another segue if I tap on the cell's accessory view.

My `UITableViewController` implements both `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` from `UITableViewDelegate`, however only the former method gets called, regardless of whether I tap on a cells accessory button or somewhere else inside the cell.

So how can the necessary distinction be made. I assume it would be possible to place a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the cell's `contentView` and use its event handler instead of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but hope there is a simpler scheme as well.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054327/storyboard-segue-from-a-tablecell-an-its-detail-disclosure-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have meanwhile found what appears to be the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296904/accessorybuttontappedforrowwithindexpath-not-getting-called/20963333#20963333):

iOS will make a distinction and call either `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` if the accessory (as set in IB) is a detail disclosure button (or detail button), but not if it is a disclosure indicator. Indeed Apple's *Podcasts* app uses a detail button in the described context.

This is the relevant excerpt from (an older version of) the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296904/accessorybuttontappedforrowwithindexpath-not-getting-called/20963333#20963333):

> Note that the detail disclosure button, unlike the disclosure
>   indicator, can perform an action that is separate from the selection
>   of the row.